# How to insert every n column in Python from Excel frame?

Tags: python, excel

Good day everyone!

I have a question how can I insert every third column in Python?
I have file frame from Excel and I need to insert every third column for a range of 100 columns, which is from column A to column BC

Does anyone know it?

I tired to loop, but It did not work

I want to have my column A and B and when a new inserted column C
my column D and E and inserted F and so on

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O. It may be a good idea for you to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see how best to ask questions. Can you show us the code you have so far? Without seeing it it`s difficult to  point out the problem. My first suggestion would be for you to loop through the columns backwards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```py
df = pd.read_csv("fileName")
newDf = pd.DataFrame()
index = 0
for column in df.columns:
    
    if index % 3 == 0:
        # every third column
        newDf[column] = df[column]

    index += 1
    print(newDf)
```